# How to print an incrementing character

Tags: python

In Python, I am trying to build a function that will print a letter and a series of random numbers on a line.  The number of lines printed will be between 1-10, dependent on user input.  The end result should look like this:

```
A 10 11 15 20 40 (actual numbers will vary, between 1-69)
B 12 15 19 30 45 
etc..
```

My problem is getting the first character to print.  I can't seem to find a way to increment the character so that the next line is B, the next after that is C, etc.

Here is what I have:

```
def generateLetter():
    value = 'A'
    newVar = (chr(ord(value[0])+1))
    value = newVar
    print(value)

def main():
    howMany = input('print how many lines?')
    count = 0
    while howMany > 10:
        if count == 3:
            break;
            count +=1
    if howMany <=10:
        print ('now printing ', howMany, 'lines')
    for each in range (howMany):
        generateLetter(),
        #another function to generate random string of numbers
```

Currently, the above results in this:

```
B
5 6 7 8 9
B
10 11 12 13 14
etc...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you examined the value of `value`?

Comment: Every time you call `generateLetter` you make `value` start at `'A'`. You need to maintain state between calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code in function `generateLetter` always print `B`. You need to pass a parameter indicating the the current step to the function.

Try this:

```
def generateLetter(i):
    print(chr(ord('A') + i))

def main():
    ...
    for each in range(howMany):
        generateLetter(each)
        ...
```

Comment: i didn't realize that setting the value = A meant that the function would reset with that value each time.  thank you for this, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use a global variable, you can stash the value there.  Also, don't increment it until you've used "A" in the first call.  Usually, this is done with a Class variable instead of a global, but you don't have a Class around this.

```
value = 'A'
def generateLetter():
    global value
    print(value)
    value = (chr(ord(value[0])+1))
```